# how to find roots of a multivariate polynomial with only one variable

Tags: sage

Say I have a multivariate polynomial ring:

```
R.<w,x,y,z> = PolynomialRing(ZZ, 4, order='lex')
```

and a polynomial contains only one variable, for example:

```
f = w^4 - 1
```

How can I find the roots of f. Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sage: f.univariate_polynomial().roots()
[(1, 1), (-1, 1)]
```